# Access vs. SQLite в linq2db в вопросах скорости

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, linq, sqlite3

Пользуюсь linq2db (https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) для запросов к БД из проекта на C#.

Есть коллекция. Класс коллекции 15 полей. В коллекции 450 элементов.

**Access**

Подключаю по инструкции с MSDN для БД типа *.accdb. 
Пишу Mapper для таблицы.
Выполняю запрос

```
var db = new RatesDB();
foreach (var rate in Rates) //Rates - та самая коллекция, что содержит 450 
{                           //элементов класса в 15 полей.
    db.TableElements
        .Value(p => p.id, () => rate.id)
        // аналогично остальные 13 полей
        .Value(p => p.score, () => rate.score)
        .Insert();
}
```

БД заполняется за **5 секунд**.

**SQLite**

Создавал при помощи SQLiteStudio ([оф.сайт софта](https://sqlitestudio.pl/)). Создавал **SQLite 3**.

Не нахожу мануала на офф.сайте. Смотрю примеры с гитхаба и [эту](https://github.com/linq2db/examples/blob/master/SQLite/GetStarted/LinqToDB.Templates/CopyMe.SQLite.tt.txt) инструкцию оттуда же. Оказалось, что это скрипт, который сгенерировал мне Mapper'ы автоматически. Посмотрел, всё вполне корректно. Выполняю команду аналогичную той, что выше и...

Она выполняется **1 минуту и 5 секунд**.

В связи с чем вопрос: это беда библиотеки [linq2db], беда самой SQLite или же это я криворукий и sqlite может работать также быстро с linq2db?

Comment: судя по всему у вас 450 открывается база и выполняется 450 транзакция (и каждая с журналом на диске) и потому время соответствующее.

Comment: @vitidev, а почему же тогда у access таких проблем со скоростью нет?

Comment: не знаю. я не знаю, что за журнал у access. А вот у Sqlite он по дефолту никак не WAL, что отражается на скорости вставки. Оберните в транзакцию. Все равно такие массовые вставки надо в одной транзакции делать

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо. после того, как обернул в транзакцию, выполнилось даже быстрее, чем с access (на мой субъективный взгляд).